# How to magnify an image while mousedown and mousemove and release when mouseup

Tags: jquery, image, mousemove, mousedown, magnify

Basicly i wanted to create a magnifying glass effect on my image while i move my mouse and hold left-mouse-button. But it acts like im dragging the picture.

I used this [magnifying example](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3)

It works perfectly when i use mousemove or mousedown action alone, but i wanna add both actions to it.

**html:**

```
<div class="magnify">
    <div class="large"></div> 
    <img class="small" title="Halten Sie die linke Maustaste-Taste für einen genaueren Blick!" src="../../Content/pictures/mypicture.png" alt="mypicture.png" />
</div>
```

**css:**

```
/* Some CSS */
.magnify { position:relative; }
/* Lets create the magnifying glass */
.large { width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute; border-radius:100%;
/* Multiple box shadows to achieve the glass effect */
/* rgba(160, 195, 219, 0.85) = #a0c3db,  rgba(73, 151, 205, 0.85) = #4997cd */
/* rgba(234, 243, 250, 0.85) = #eaf3fa,  rgba(57, 136, 191, 0.85) = #3988bf */
box-shadow:0 0 0 9px rgba(73, 151, 205, 0.75), 
           0 0 7px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 
     inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
/* Lets load up the large image first */
background:url(/Content/pictures/mypicture.png) no-repeat;
/* hide the glass by default */
display:none; cursor:pointer;
}
/* To solve overlap bug at the edges during magnification */
.small { display:block; width:800px; border-radius:20px 20px 20px 20px; }
```

**jquery:**

```
var leftButtonDown = false;
$(document).ready(function ()
{   //define zero
    var native_width = 0;
    var native_height = 0;
    //Now the mousemove function
    $(".magnify").mousemove(function (e)
    {
        $(".magnify").bind('mousedown', function (en)
        {
            if (en.which === 1) { leftButtonDown = false; }
        }).bind('mouseup', function (en)
        {
            if (en.which === 1) { leftButtonDown = true; }
        })

        if (leftButtonDown == true) {
            //When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
            //the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
            //are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
            if (!native_width && !native_height) {
                //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
                //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
                //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
                //created this image object.
                var image_object = new Image();
                image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");
                //This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
                //width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
                //the image gets loaded.
                native_width = image_object.width;
                native_height = image_object.height;
            } else {
                //x/y coordinates of the mouse
                //This is the position of .magnify with respect to the document.
                var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
                //We will deduct the positions of .magnify from the mouse positions with
                //respect to the document to get the mouse positions with respect to the 
                //container(.magnify)
                var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
                var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;
                //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
                if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
                    $(".large").fadeIn(100);
                } else {
                    $(".large").fadeOut(100);
                }
                if ($(".large").is(":visible")) {
                    //The background position of .large will be changed according to the position
                    //of the mouse over the .small image. So we will get the ratio of the pixel
                    //under the mouse pointer with respect to the image and use that to position the 
                    //large image inside the magnifying glass
                    var rx = Math.round(mx / $(".small").width() * native_width - $(".large").width() / 2) * -1;
                    var ry = Math.round(my / $(".small").height() * native_height - $(".large").height() / 2) * -1;
                    var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";
                    //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
                    var px = mx - $(".large").width() / 2;
                    var py = my - $(".large").height() / 2;
                    //Now the glass moves with the mouse
                    //The logic is to deduct half of the glass's width and height from the 
                    //mouse coordinates to place it with its center at the mouse coordinates
                    //If you hover on the image now, you should see the magnifying glass in action
                    $(".large").css({ left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp });
                }
            }
        } //endif leftButtonDown == true
    })
})
```

Comment: which browser are you using, does it matter to you ?

Comment: @SreenathSoman the solution must be crossbrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are as follows:

**1. You have your `leftButtonDown = true/false` the wrong way round in the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.**

**2. It is also worthwhile to convert the `mouseup` event to bind to the `document` (in case the we have `mousedown` inside the image, and `mouseup` outside the image).**

**3. Add `en.preventDefault` to `mousedown` to stop it causing Firefox or some browsers from trying to drag the image instead.**

**4. Add `fadeOut` to `mouseup` to tweak behaviour (so that it fades even if the mouse doesn't move immediately after mouseup).

```js
$(".magnify").bind('mousedown', function (en)
{
    if (en.which === 1) {
        leftButtonDown = true;
        en.preventDefault();
    }
})
$(document).bind('mouseup', function (en)
{
    if (en.which === 1) {
      leftButtonDown = false;
      $(".large").fadeOut(100);
    }
})
```

**5. Move the above block of code outside of your `mousemove` event handler. You only need to run that code once. So leave it just inside `$(document).ready` where it belongs.**

**6. Your `if ( leftButtonDown ) { ... }` guard needs to be moved. Remove it and move the condition check into your `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` condition.**

Notice the `&& leftButtonDown` at the end of the condition.

```js
if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0
    && leftButtonDown )
{
  $(".large").fadeIn(100);
} else {
  $(".large").fadeOut(100);
}
```

For more details, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pAav/4/).

---

I assume you haven't tried adding the code to magnify the image inside the magnifying glass yet. I will leave that for you to complete.

Comment: this still has the problem. while mouse-down and mouse-move the magnifier glass stays put. as i mentioned before the problem is using mouse-move with mouse-down. I guess i will need something like prevent default then try making magnifier visible and move with mouse.

Comment: really? try the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9pAav/3/, it seems to work in my browser. I mouse-down inside the image, and keeping the mouse button down, the circle moves with the mouse.

Comment: this works in safari, maxthon but not in ie, firefox.. here is the issue: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/14/thisiswhathappens.jpg/ this looks like a bug to me..

Comment: Ok, knowing that it doesn't work in Firefox, I was able to fix it. Answer above changed to reflect changes.

Comment: Dude you just created mouse-hold-event without causing any bug, gratz! You earned it. :D